# Excel: Conditional formatting for x number of days before

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to set a conditional formatting for an expiration date field. The idea is to show via color coding (green, yellow, and red) when the expiration date is approaching according to the cell (In the E column) and today's date.

It should fill green when the date in the field is equal or after today

```
=E3>TODAY()
```

It should fill yellow when the date in the field is less than today and less than 3 months (90 days) (between 89 days and yesterday)

```
=AND(E3<TODAY(),E3>(TODAY()-90))
```

It should fill red when the date in the field is less than 3 months (90 days)

```
=E3<=TODAY()-90
```

[image: Excel Screenshot]

The colors do not match my date ranges.

**EDIT:**

I have updated my original post to include more info and updated screenshot example.

I included the dates (including "today's date") as reference. I added the conditional Formatting Rules formula in the cells. I included the Correction column to show what the correct color should be.

Comment: `=AND(H3 > TODAY()-90, H3 < TODAY())`?

Comment: Is the order of the conditions important? I have the order as yellow, green, red.

Comment: Depending on how you lay out the formulas, it may be. With these formulas, it isn't. If your data starts in H3 but you apply the formula to the entire H:H, the result will be shifted two cells down. If you want to apply the formula to entire H:H, change H3 to H1.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the conditional format and edited my entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the rule type from **Use a formula to determine which cells to format** to **Format Cells that contain**.

It worked perfectly.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have:

[image]

And this order on the conditional formatting:

[image]

Formulae used:

Green:

```
=D6>=TODAY()
```

Yellow:

```
=AND(D4<TODAY(),D4>(TODAY()-90))
```

Red:

```
=D5<=TODAY()-90
```

Update:

With 14/03/2023

[image]

Comment: For some reason Some future dates comes in red.

Comment: hmm odd, i just tried that on my and it is green ( added screenshot) (note i'm using dd-MM-yyyy - not that it should make a difference). Have you cleared all your conditional formats before starting again?

Comment: I noticed that in the screenshot, you used D7, but different in the formula text. I used the same for my conditions as the screenshot

Comment: Make sure it's not just 'Current Selection', but you change this to 'This Worksheet'

Comment: @Rick `For some reason Some future dates comes in red` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65874660/excel-conditional-formatting-for-x-number-of-days-before#comment116470829_65874660?

Comment: @Rick I have added the screenshot to match what i used in the actual conditional formatting for D7 (Red, Yellow and Green). The ones in Col H i used for testing each one individually (Rows 2 to 4). I have tried various future dates and they all go to green for me

Comment: E7,F7, and G7 are what I have to enter in the formula for each respective conditional format, correct? All with the starting cell D7 in this case, right?

Comment: @v-c0de I updated my screenshot and included more information to see what I'm doing wrong.